# Problemas con replaceAll en javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero reemplazar todos los caracteres del input type text, he visto en internet que se usa /g, pero cuando lo pongo yo, me salta un error que no está "definido"

```
  function replaceAllInvalidCharacter(id){
        var characters = ["/","\\", "¿","?","#","<",">","[","]","{","}","%","="];
    var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

    for(var i = 0 ; i < characters.length; i++){
        if (val.indexOf(characters[i]) != -1) {
            val = val.replace(characters[i]/g, '');
        } 
    }
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
 }
```

error ->

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined
```

¿Cómo hago para que coga todos los caracteres?

Por ejemplo: e/d/u m/o/l/a y se quede con edu mola ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que quieres hacer se hace con un Regex (Expresion regular) y por lo que pones seria la siguiente `[/"\\¿?#<>\[\]{}%=]+` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```js
function replaceAllInvalidCharacter(id){
    var characters = /[/"\\¿?#<>\[\]{}%=]+/g;
    var val = document.getElementById(id).value;    
    val = val.replace(characters, '');        
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
 }
```

Comment: Creo que esta respuesta es la más optima para el OP, sintetiza toda la expresión regular en una sola y evita el ciclo.

Comment: Perfecto, funciona perfectamente ,gracias entendiste muy bien el problema !

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, los árboles no me dejaron ver el bosque: esta respuesta simplifica todo el escenario y es más eficiente.

Answer (score 6):

Intentar concatenar `/g` ahí no tiene sentido, ya que sólo se puede usar con RegExp literales. Por tanto tienes dos opciones:

1. Montar previamente todas las regexp.
2. Usar el constructor de la clase RegExp, que recibe un string para la regexp y otro para los modificadores.

Ejemplos:

```js
function replaceAllInvalidCharacter(id){
  var characters = [/\//g,/\\/g, /=/g];
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

  for(var i = 0 ; i < characters.length; i++){
    val = val.replace(characters[i], ''); 
  }
  document.getElementById(id).value = val;
 }
 
 replaceAllInvalidCharacter('inp');
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="En /un \lug=ar =/\de la Mancha"/>
```

```js
function replaceAllInvalidCharacter(id){
  var characters = ["/","\\\\", "¿","\\?","#","<",">","\\[","\\]","{","}","%","="];
  var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

  for(var i = 0 ; i < characters.length; i++){
    val = val.replace(new RegExp(characters[i],'g'), '');
  }
  document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
 
 replaceAllInvalidCharacter('inp');
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="En /un \lug=ar =/\de la Mancha"/>
```

Como puedes ver, trabajar con literales es más cómodo (no necesitas el doble `\` para *escapar* caracteres), pero en cualquier caso no podrás usar el indexof para buscar primero, aunque no es necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Bastaría con recorrer la colección de caracteres inválidos en un array.map y reemplazarlos por ''

```
function replaceAllInvalidCharacter(id){
    var characters = ["/","\\", "¿","?","#","<",">","[","]","{","}","%","="];
    var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

    characters.map(function(char){
        val.replace(char, '');
    });

    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
```

Comment: No funciona exactamente como el OP pide: `/g` indica que la búsqueda es global, tu código sólo reemplazaría la primera coincidencia

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que ese /g que estas intentando utilizar es de una expresion regular, pero el valor character no lo es.

Para solucionarlo,tenes que instanciar una expresion regular. Utilizá el siguiente código:

```
function replaceAllInvalidCharacter(id){
    var characters = ["/","\\", "¿","?","#","<",">","[","]","{","}","%","="];
    var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

    for(var i = 0 ; i < characters.length; i++){
        if (val.indexOf(characters[i]) != -1) {
            var re = new RegExp(characters[i], "g");
            val = val.replace(re, '');
        } 
    }
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
```

Para más documentación acerca de las expresiones regulares, https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp

Comment: Este código no termina de funcionar: Hay que escapar doblemente la barra invertida (backslash) y algunos caracteres como los corchetes darían problemas también